# Reverse input order with sed

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, sed

I have a file, lets call it 'a.txt' and this file contains the following text line

```
do to what
```

I'm wondering what the SED command is to reverse the order of this text to make it look like

```
what to do
```

Do I have to do some sort of append? Like append 'do' to 'to' so it would look like

to ++ do (used ++ just to make it clear)

Comment: Is the number of words constant (i.e. always three)?

Comment: This will be horrible to do in `sed`.  Do you have to use it?  In Perl: `perl -lane 'print join " ", reverse @F'`.

Comment: I want it to work for an arbitrary amount of words to make it more generic.

Found this sed command
sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
But it reverse the order of the words as well.

Comment: why on earth did you pick `sed`?

Comment: Because I found the replacement method(s/,/./g) for instance to be very easy to work with.

Comment: I don't see the correlation. For the same reason, you could also use it to control nuclear reactors...

Comment: I want a one-liner command to edit my whole file without having to run scripts.

Comment: @user1634254 - then store the commands in a script.  That's what they're for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) answer

As this question was tagged [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), my 1st answer was:

First (using arbitraty `_` to mark viewed spaces, when `a.txt` contain `do to what`:

```
sed -e '
    :a;
    s/\([^_]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2_\1/;
    ta;
    y/_/ /;
   ' a.txt
what to do
```

than, when `a.txt` contain `do to to what`:

```
sed -e '
    :a;
    s/^\(\|.* \)\([^+ ]\+\) \2\([+]*\)\(\| .*\)$/\1\2\3+\4/g;
    ta;
    :b;
    s/\([^_]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2_\1/;
    tb;
    y/_/ /;
   ' <<<'do to to to what'
what to++ do
```

There is one `+` for each *supressed* duplicated word:

```
sed -e ':a;s/^\(\|.* \)\([^+ ]\+\) \2\([+]*\)\(\| .*\)$/\1\2\3+\4/g;ta;
        :b;s/\([^_]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2_\1/;tb;
        y/_/ /;' <<<'do do to what what what what'
what+++ to do+
```

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) answer

But as there is a lot of people searching for simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solutions, there is a simple way:

```
xargs < <(uniq <(tac <(tr \  \\n <<<'do do to what what what what')))
what to do
```

this could be written:

```
tr \  \\n <<<'do do to what what what what' | tac | uniq | xargs 
what to do
```

or even with some [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) scripting:

```
revcnt () { 
    local wrd cnt plut out="";
    while read cnt wrd; do
        printf -v plus %$((cnt-1))s;
        out+=$wrd${plus// /+}\ ;
    done < <(uniq -c <(tac <(tr \  \\n )));
    echo $out
}
```

Will do:

```
revcnt <<<'do do to what what what what' 
what+++ to do+
```

### Or as *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)*

```
revcnt() { 
    local out i;
    for ((i=$#; i>0; i--))
    do
        [[ $out =~ ${!i}[+]*$ ]] && out+=+ || out+=\ ${!i};
    done;
    echo $out
}
```

where submited string have to be submitted as argument:

```
revcnt do do to what what what what
what+++ to do+
```

Or if prossessing *standard input* (or from file) is required:

```
revcnt() { 
    local out i arr;
    while read -a arr; do
        out=""
        for ((i=${#arr[@]}; i--; 1))
        do
            [[ $out =~ ${arr[i]}[+]*$ ]] && out+=+ || out+=\ ${arr[i]};
        done;
        echo $out;
    done
}
```

So you can process multiple lines:

```
revcnt <<eof
do to what
do to to to what
do do to what what what what
eof
what to do
what to++ do
what+++ to do+
```

Comment: `revcnt < <(rev <<< 'esaelP etovpu !siht )-;')`

Answer (score 8):

I know `tac` can do something related

```
$ cat file
 do to what
$ tac -s' ' file

what to do  $
```

Where the `-s` defines the separator, which is by default a newline.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk` to do this:

```
awk '{ for (i=NF; i>=1; i--) printf (i!=1) ? $i OFS : $i "\n" }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
what to do
```

***EDIT***:

If you require a one-liner to modify your file "in-place", try:

```
{ rm file.txt && awk '{ for (i=NF; i>=1; i--) printf (i!=1) ? $i OFS : $i "\n" }' > file.txt; } < file.txt
```

Comment: **+1** - that's exactly what I would do.  Except that I would use `ORS` instead of `"\n"`.  Oh, and the one-liner...  That looks (wooo) scary.  I'd prefer to make a temp file, then move it into place if the command succeeds.  Your version definitely kills the file if your filesystem is full.

Comment: @ghoti: Thanks mate. It's an interesting solution I came across a few days ago. But you're right, perhaps something like `awk '{ ... }' file.txt > temp && mv temp file.txt` would be safer.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'G;:a;s/^\n//;t;s/^(\S+|\s+)(.*)\n/\2\n\1/;ta' file
```

Explanation:

- `G` add a newline to the end of the pattern space (PS)
- `:a` loop name space
- `s/^\n//;t` when the newline is at the front of the PS, remove it and print line
- `s/^(\S+|\s+)(.*)\n/\2\n\1/;ta` insert either a non-space or a space string directly after the newline and loop to `:a`

The `-r` switch makes the regexp easier-on-the-eye (grouping `(...)`, alternation `...|...` and the metacharacter for one-or-more `+` are relieved of the need of a backslash prefix).

Alternative:

```
sed -E 'G;:a;s/^(\S+)(\s*)(.*\n)/\3\2\1/;ta;s/.//' file
```

N.B. To reverse the line, adapt the above solution to:

```
sed -E 'G;:a;/^(.)(.*\n)/\2\1/;ta;s/.//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like perl for this:

```
perl -F -lane '@rev=reverse(@F);print "@rev"' your_file
```

Comment: I get `t a h w   o t   o d` with this, the `-F` does a `split //`, if `-F` is removed it works.

This could be shortened a bit by using the output field separator: `$,=" "; print reverse @F`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Bernhard said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108568/52499), `tac` can be used here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
echo '1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5' | while IFS= read -r; do
    echo -n "$REPLY " | tac -s' '
    echo
done

$ ./1.sh
3 2 1 
4 3 2 
5 4 3
```

I believe my example is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**SED**:

When you know the exact words you want to exchange:

```
$ cat a.txt
do to what

$ sed -ri '/do.*what/ s/do/what/' a.txt

$ cat a.txt
what to what

$ sed -ri '/what.*what/ s/what$/do/' a.txt

$ cat a.txt
what to do
```

But you must know exactly where the words are located, their circumstances, what words surround them, whether they are at the beginning or end of a sentence/line, etc. The right metacharacters to be used will depend on this information.